# SpringIntegration publish to kafka and update couchbase after receiving a message from MQ

Tags: spring-integration-dsl

I am using SpringIntegration's IntegrationFlows to define the message flow, and used Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter to get the message from the MQ, now I need to parse it, send it to KAFKA and update couchbase.

```
IntegrationFlows
                .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(this.acarsMqListener))  //MQ Listener with session transacted=true
                .wireTap(ACARS_WIRE_TAP_CHNL)                                 // Logging the message
                .transform(agmTransformer, "parseXMLMessage")                 // Parse the xml message
                .filter(acarsFilter,"filterMessageOnSmi")                     // Filter the message based on condition
                .transform(agmTransformer, "populateImi")                     // Parse and Populate based on the message payload
                .filter(acarsFilter,"filterMessageOnSmiImi")                  // Filter the message based on condition
                .handle(acarsProcessor, "processEvent")                       // Create the message
                .handle(Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaTemplate).messageKey(MESSAGE_KEY).topic(acarsKafkaTopic))  //send it to kafka
                .handle(updateCouchbase, "saveToDB")                          // Update couchbase
                .get();
```

As per the application logic - the message should be stored in kafka and couchbase, if there is any exception in storing the message into kafka and couchbase the message should be rolled back to the queue. Is the above message flow cater the expected behavior? Can you please suggest if any improvement can be done?